# Android percentage bar onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

i'm New on java and coding, i try to learn how to code in Android studio and i try some exercises.

I want to create code for 2 buttons: bt1 and bt2. When users clicks on bt1, a progress bar show percentage of click on this bt1.

Any other help/approach to this solution will also be appreciable.

Comment: Hi! You said *When users clicks on bt1, a progress bar show percentage of click on this bt1* but it doesn't make sense for me. What is bt2 button for?

Comment: @IlyaKovalyov hi! users have the choice to click between 2 buttons. if 30 people out of 100 click on bt1 we will have a progress bar of 30% and thus 70% on bt2

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand why you would have 50% on a progress bar. Did you mean 30% on btn 1 and 70% on btn 2?

Comment: @IlyaKovalyov hooo sorry yes 30%

Comment: @IlyaKovalyov you know what i want to mean?

Comment: yes, I'm working on the code and will send the solution with some tips in a minute or so :)

Comment: @IlyaKovalyov thanks a lot!

Comment: if my solution helped you, please upvote it and mark it as the answer to your question so that others might know that it was useful.
And you are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as far as I understood from your description and our conversation, you need a progress bar that will display percentage between clicks on first and second buttons. If you create an Empty Activity project and replace all these things in the following files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn1;
Button btn2;

ProgressBar myBar;

TextView score1;
TextView score2;

TextView percent1;
TextView percent2;

private float firstClicked;
private float secondClicked;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    myBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    score1 = findViewById(R.id.score1);
    score2 = findViewById(R.id.score2);

    percent1 = findViewById(R.id.percent1);
    percent2 = findViewById(R.id.percent2);


    firstClicked = 0;
    secondClicked = 0;

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firstClicked++;
            score1.setText(String.valueOf((int) firstClicked));
            updateProgressTab();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            secondClicked++;
            score2.setText(String.valueOf((int) secondClicked));
            updateProgressTab();
        }
    });

    updateProgressTab();
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void updateProgressTab() {
    float progress;

    if (firstClicked != 0 && secondClicked != 0) {
        progress = (firstClicked / (firstClicked + secondClicked)) * 100;
        percent1.setText((int) progress + "%");
        percent2.setText((int) (100 - progress) + "%");
    } else if (firstClicked == 0 && secondClicked == 0) {
        progress = 50;
    } else if (firstClicked == 0) {
        progress = 0;
    } else {
        progress = 100;
    }

    percent1.setText((int) progress + "%");
    percent2.setText((int) (100 - progress) + "%");

    myBar.setProgress((int) progress, true);
}
```

}

(don't forget to auto-import all the stuff)

**custom_progressbar.xml** needs to be created in the `res/drawable` folder

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#000001"
            android:centerColor="#0b131e"
            android:centerY="1.0"
            android:endColor="#0d1522"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#007A00"
                android:centerColor="#007A00"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

**activity_main.sml** in the `res/layout` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="#007A00"
    android:text="@string/button_one"
    android:textColor="#FCF8F8"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="#0B131E"
    android:text="@string/button_two"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/_0"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/score2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/score1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/percent1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="50%"
    android:textColor="#007A00"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/percent2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:text="50%"
    android:textColor="#0B131E"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Remember, that my project is called ***ProgressBar*** thus if you call your *Empty Project* a **ProgressBar** you technically don't need to replace anything else.

You can learn from all the little things in the code but this is basically the assignment you asked to make. If you struggle understanding certain things, use `Ctrl+Shift+F` for Windows and `Command+Shift+F` for Mac to search for stuff across projects.